# MySql If Then in Select Statement

Tags: mysql

I want to use an IF THEN statement in a mysql select, but can't figure it out. When there are no comments yet, the commentcreated value should be the created value of the item itself. This is the query:

```
SELECT item.*, 
  count(comments.itemid) AS commentcount, 
  max(comments.created) AS commentcreated 
FROM table_items AS item 
LEFT JOIN table_comments AS comments ON (comments.itemid = item.id) 
WHERE item.published=1 
GROUP BY item.id 
ORDER BY item.created DESC
```

I'd figured this, but it doesn't work:

```
...
, IF max(comments.created)!='NULL'
THEN max(comments.created) AS commentcreated
ELSE item.created AS commentcreated
END IF;
FROM .......
```

What is the (best) way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Can use `IFNULL`

```
IFNULL(max(comments.created), item.created) AS commentcreated
```

OR `IF`

```
IF(max(comments.created)='NULL', max(comments.created), item.created) 
AS commentcreated
```

Answer (score 4):

```
coalesce(max(comments.created), item.created) as commentcreated
```

Comment: Also works great! Any reason to choose this one over: IFNULL(max(comments.created), item.created) AS commentcreated?

Comment: I didn't know MySQL had `IFNULL`, that is fine too. `COALESCE` handles more than 2 values, which you don't need in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the IF...THEN...ELSE construction inline in a single statement, as part of an expression to produce a single value - that's what the IFNULL and COALESCE functions are for, as ajreal and Redfilter have suggested.

IF...THEN...ELSE only works in a block of SQL code including a number of different statements e.g. in a stored procedure.